# How to count nested elements inside a model?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm building an app with Express, Postgres as db and Sequelize as ORM.

This is the response I get:

```
{
  "user": {
    "user_name": "John",
    "post": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-04-16T22:52:59.054Z",
        "post_titles": [
          {
            "title_id": 3571
          },
          {
            "title_id": 3570
          },
          {
            "title_id": 3569
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

How can I count how many titles there are in the post?

I have 4 models:
`User`, hasMany `Posts` 
`Post`, has many `Titles` through `PostTitles` 
`Title` 
`PostTitle`

This is my query:

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: req.params.id },
  attributes: ['id', 'user_name'],
  include: [
    { model: Post,
      attributes: ['id', 'created_at'],
      include: {
        model: PostTitles,
        attributes: ['title_id']
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` function .

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: req.params.id },
  attributes: ['id', 'user_name'],
  include: [
    { model: Post,
      attributes: ['id', 'created_at'],
      include: {
        model: PostTitles,
        attributes: ['title_id',[Sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT(title_id))'), 'totalcount']]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I get this error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I added `group: 'users.id'` but I got ` invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "post_titles"

Comment: pass group by users.id too. and check again
`group : ['users.id']`